# How to change this code to calculate the sum of elements below main diagonal of a matrix

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This code calculate the sum of main diagonal of a matrix. How to change the for condition?

```
 public static double Suma(double[,]t,int n,int m)
    {
        double s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j< m; j++)
            {
                if (i==j) 
                s+=t[i,j];
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: why change it if it works? what's your reason, what's your intention? what have you tried?

Comment: `i==j` -> Element is on diagonal; `i > j` - element is above diagonal; `i < j` ... voila!

Comment: i need to calculate the sum of elements below main diagonal, and idk how. This is a school project and i need help.

Comment: we're not here to write the code for you... please show what you have tried or draw a picture (even with ascii text) to describe what the matrix traversal is doing in the code you have posted.  It's ok to answer your own question on stackoverflow, and often fully describing the problem helps you to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the `for` conditions - they are needed in order to examine each element of the array. Instead, you need to change the comparison of the row and column indexes in the `if` condition.

Currently your code checks to see if `row == col`, and if they do, then we know we're on the diagonal and we add the value to our `sum`. But since you want to change the code to sum the cells that are *below* the diagonal (which is when the `row` index is *greater than* the `column` index), then we need to change the `if` condition to `row > col`:

```
public static double SumBelowDiagonal(double[,] matrix)
{
    var rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    var cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
    double sum = 0;

    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            if (row > col) sum += matrix[row, col];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

---

Another approach would be to create a single method that takes in an array and a "comparison type", so we don't have to write three different methods that essentially have the same code. We can make use of the `Compare` method, knowing that it returns `-1` for "less than", `0` for "equal to", and `1` for "greater than". Knowing this, we can create an `enum` to make the code more readable, and re-write our method like:

```
public enum DiagonalCompare
{
    Above = -1,
    On = 0,
    Below = 1
}

public static double SumDiagonal(double[,] matrix, DiagonalCompare comparison)
{
    var rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    var cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
    double sum = 0;

    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            if (row.CompareTo(col) == (int) comparison)
                sum += matrix[row, col];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Now our code that calls this method might look something like:

```
var sumAbove = SumDiagonal(matrix, DiagonalCompare.Above);
var sumBelow = SumDiagonal(matrix, DiagonalCompare.Below);
var sumOnDiag = SumDiagonal(matrix, DiagonalCompare.On);
```

Here's a sample of how it might look in use:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var size = 5;
    var matrix = new double[size, size];

    // Populate array and write it to the console
    for (var row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            matrix[row, col] = row * size + col;

            // Change color for above, on, and below diagnoal
            Console.ForegroundColor = row > col
                ? ConsoleColor.Cyan
                : row == col
                    ? ConsoleColor.Magenta
                    : ConsoleColor.Green;

            Console.Write(matrix[row, col].ToString("00") + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Display the sums using our method above
    Console.WriteLine("Sum Above Diagonal:  " +
                      SumDiagonal(matrix, DiagonalCompare.Above));
    Console.WriteLine("Sum Below Diagonal:  " +
                      SumDiagonal(matrix, DiagonalCompare.Below));
    Console.WriteLine("Sum on the Diagonal: " +
                      SumDiagonal(matrix, DiagonalCompare.On));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]